# Java jsoup - clean all tags except link

Tags: java, android, jsoup, strip-tags

Input string:

`<b>Test link</b> <a href="https://www.w3schools.com">Visit W3Schools</a>`

Expected result:

`Test link <a href="https://www.w3schools.com">Visit W3Schools</a>`

My try with jsoup:

```
public String cleanHtml(String html)
    {
        Whitelist whitelist = Whitelist.none();
        whitelist.addTags("a");

        return Jsoup.clean(html, whitelist);
    }
```

Result is:

`Test link <a>Visit W3Schools</a>`

How can I remove all tags, but keep entire `a href`?

Answer (score 6):

You need to use `addAttributes` . here you pass list of allowed attributes,`whitelist.addAttributes("a","href","id","more")`;

Try with this:

```
String html = "<b>Test link</b> <a href=\"https://www.w3schools.com\">Visit W3Schools</a>";
    Whitelist whitelist = Whitelist.none();
    whitelist.addTags("a");
    whitelist.addAttributes("a","href");

    System.out.println(Jsoup.clean(html, whitelist));
```